# Converting from "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss" to local showing different results in Google Chrome and IE

Tags: javascript, html, date, datetime

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
    <title>Date Time Issue</title> </head> <body>
    <script>
       var dateInOtherFormat = "2017-02-02T13:00:00";
       var localDate = new Date(dateInOtherFormat);
       document.body.innerHTML = localDate;
    </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Converting from "**yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss**" format **to** **local time** showing different results in different browsers.

Comment: Use localDate.toISOString()

Comment: @YOU In Chrome : 2017-02-02T13:00:00.000Z , In IE : 2017-02-02T07:30:00.000Z  ......... My timezone is +05:30 . In chrome, it is advanced by 05:30 hour

Comment: have you tried .toLocaleString()?

Comment: @SanjayPatel Chrome : 2/2/2017, 6:30:00 PM IE : ‎2‎/‎2‎/‎2017‎ ‎13‎:‎00‎:‎00

Comment: `new Date(dateInOtherFormat+"Z")`

Answer (score -1):

You can write a method for checking what the browser is. Then to the different browser use different code.